# How to share battle execution code between client and server?

Tags: architecture, client-server

We're making an online turn-based game. There's some logic that is executed in both client and server side. Here's the pseudocode that shows how we share the code:

```
// Shared Code
class BattleExecutor {
  constructor(eventHandler)

  void ExecuteTurn(userInputs) {
    ......
    trigger events such as Move, Fire, TakeDamage
    ......
  }
}

// Server
new BattleExecutor(noOperationHandler)

// Client
class ClientEventHandler {
  // play Move, Fire, TakeDamage anime
}

new BattleExecutor(new ClientEventHandler())
```

In this design, the shared BattleExecutor has the logic of how game is played. Client code is just to play the anime for the events that triggered in BattleExecutor. Server needs the BattleExecutor to determine if user inputs are valid and to determine battle result (who won).

Now our problem is, think of this scenario, in one turn BattleExecutor triggers a Fire and a TakeDamage event within 1 millisecond. But in client side TakeDamage can only be played when Fire anime is done (bullet flying takes time). **How to control the playing of events in client side?**

The solution we're considering is to add "Id" and "DependOnIds" property to Event class, meaning that BattleExecutor provides the information of "event A should happen after events B, C, D". Client knows when anime of B, C, D is done playing, after which client starts playing anime of A. This solution looks a little messy to us, because BattleExecutor now needs to figure out the dependency of events which server doesn't care about at all.

Is there any more elegant solution that can share battle execution code between client/server and allow client to control the playing of events correctly?

Comment: My apologies, I missed part of your question. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Almo, our team is new in this area. We did some research and thought a lot about the design of the specific question asked here. But we still don't have a satisfactory answer. Maybe this's a entry-level question and already been well discussed. Any links would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You can either do a callback, like have an onHitRecieved function that gets called after a client gets hit (fire animation finished), this function will tell the server which client got hit and do broadcast based on that.

Other than that you can create a stack, where you can add events and the client will sequentially resolve each one

Comment: Thanks @Vince.
We thought about callback way, but our game is that server receives all user inputs of one turn and execute them all together. Eg, when the engine (the code that we want to share between C/S) triggers a Fire event, it immediately knows which target is hit, so it doesn't make much sense for client to tell server "I finish playing animation, you can continue".
The stack approach is what we're currently thinking of. A little more complicated, we plan to create an event tree, children nodes can only be played when parent node is done playing. We're seeking for any more elegant way

Comment: If you don't have events that need to appear simultaneous, it seems to me that you can just execute the events sequentially on the client - except that some events will take several frames. The client can already determine based on the type of the event if it's a long running event, so on the face of it, it doesn't look like you need to change anything on the server side. In this scenario, all you need is something like `if (noEventRunning) event = pendingEvents.Dequeue();` followed by `UpdateEvent(event, timeElapsed);`. 1/2

Comment: But if you do have what needs to appear to the player as several simultaneous threads of execution, then the server needs to provide some kind of a tree structure. It doesn't matter that the server doesn't need this tree structure in order to *execute* these events, what matters is that clients need this information, and only the server can provide it - this is because these aren't static dependencies between different types of events, these are dynamic dependencies between event instances, as they unfolded in that particular gameplay scenario. 2/2

Comment: @FilipMilovanović, thanks for your detailed reply. We do need some events happening simultaneously (imagine a few bullets are fired at the same time, each has different flying time), so a queue doesn't work. As you said, a tree(graph) structure is the best one we can find so far.

Comment: Also, if you're willing to reconceptualize things, another thing you could do is, instead of sending a tree of events (possibly rather complicated to construct), you could send a sequence of data points, each representing the full state of the world (or incremental updates from a previously known state), for some fixed update frequency, and "replay" those on the client. I.e., instead of two separate "bullet fired" events, you send the state of the world at some instant - some kind of description like "bullet 1 is at (x1, y1, z1), velocity v1, bullet 2 is at (x2, y2, z2), velocity v2, etc."

Comment: Another way to think about it is that, instead of discrete events, you'd be sending a bunch of animation frames. (Of course, this would require changes on the server, because it now needs to run the simulation. Not in real time - it would do it really fast, but in a number of cycles. The client would then replay it with proper timing. So this requires some rework, but perhaps it's worth considering).

Comment: @FilipMilovanović. The game is turn-based board game, server doesn't know bullets' flying speed at all, only client knows it for playing animation. So, it would go too far to let server calculate frames. Thanks for your ideas again.